# Get clientIp during build in sveltekit is returing an error "can't get clientip during prerendering"

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, sveltekit-adapter-node

I'm attempting to get the clientip inside hooks.server.js in sveltekit app for the first time. I get an error "Cannot read clientAddress during prerendering "

My hooks.server.js file is basic :

```
import { sequence } from '@sveltejs/kit/hooks'; 
export const prerender = false;

export const runauthjs = SvelteKitAuth({
    providers: [
        EmailProvider({" config "}),
        AppleProvider({clientId : "", clientSecret : ""})
    ],
});

export const getip = async ({ event, resolve }) => {
    
    let requestIp = event.getClientAddress(); // IP from Client Request
    console.log('IP Address from Client Request: ', requestIp);
  
    const response = await resolve(event);
    return response;

  };


  export async function handleError({ error, event, status, message }) {

    console.log("error : ", error )

  }

  export const handle = sequence(runauthjs, getip);
```

When I use : npm run build
I get an error : error :  Error: Cannot read clientAddress during prerendering

I moved the get ip function to layout.server.js, same message.

In dev, everything is working as expected. But I'm unable to get the build to complete. It throw the aforementioned error.

I need the ip to lookup user location.

How do I get the clientip and get the app to build?

Comment: you cannot use the client ip and prerender at the same time, prerendering is by definition independent of the client and the client ip isn't

Comment: I have prerender : false on top. What else do I need to do to build the app. I need the ip for certain functionality.